# Use one json file instead of two Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I load data from two json files based on radio button value...It's working fine ..But now I want to use one json file instead of two...I mean having both json data in one json file and we load acording to rado button value.How can I do that?

Comment: They are JS objects. Nothing stops you from doing something like: `myObjectFromFile1: {}; myObjectFromFile2: {}` in just one file.

Comment: By putting both JSON data in one file, what problem or issue you are addressing? Script combining can be used with the help of grunt/gulp client side tools.

Comment: provide JSON and code sample

Comment: finally worked Add two json files in one json...[[1st json],[2nd json]]...

Comment: get..                                                                                                    $scope. data= response.data[0];        $scope. data= response.data[1];